# Xpath to find the first child if a sibling contains certain text

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to find the XPATH for `<li>Test1</li>` in this case if the list contains `<li>Sample</li>`.

Example of Tags:

```
<ul>
        <li>Test1</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Sample</li>
</ul>

<ul>
        <li>TestA</li>
        <li>TestB</li>
        <li>TestC</li>
</ul>
```

There can be multiple `<ul>` tags

Have been able to find whether li contains Sample using below query

```
//ul/li[contains(.,'Sample')]
```

Any thoughts on how to find the xpath of `<li>Test1</li>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this xpath:

```
//ul[contains(li,'Sample')]/li[1]
```

The idea is to first find the `ul` element that has a `li` element that contains `'Sample'`.  Then from that, select the first `li` in that node set.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. The above works fine !!!! Modified the original one also like this //ul/li[contains(.,'Sample')]/../li[1] which also works fine.